# Use PHP in static Block by calling .phtml

Tags: php-5.4, static-block

I'm having problems with getting a .phtml file that contains some php to show in a static block. I've been searching the web and SO for days but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a static block called *"block_product_secondary_bottom"*. In this block I have various html code and text which displays in the area that I want it to (on the product page). So I'm comfortable with setting up static blocks.

What I've tried to do is create a .phtml containg PHP and include this in the block. The .phtml file is located in "/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/myphp/myphpcode.phtml"

The .phtml file simply contains:

```
<?php 
echo "Here I will write my custom PHP code";
?>
```

In the static block above my text (that shows correctly) i've put:

```
12345:{{block type="catalog/product_view" template="myphp/myphpcode.phtml"}}
```

I've put the 12345: to test make sure I know where the code should be. This shows, but there is nothing after it.

Please could you point me in the right direction, like I said I've spent days trying to figure this out!

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert template in cms page

```
 {{block type="core/template" name="my.block.name" template="myfolder/newfile.phtml"}}
```

try replacing "my.block.name" with "product.advertiser" and change template path as per your requirement.

Comment: Perfect! After literally days of trying to figure it out, it was because I didn't have the "name" section in the block. This helped me fix the issue!